# Struggling with a top level FragmentPagerAdapter containing a Fragment with its own FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

Have a 2 level UI, The top level has a tab strip powered by a FragmentPagerAdapter. One of the fragments in turn has a 2nd level FragmentPagerAdapter and its own tab strip carrying a couple of "sub"fragments. Now, the sub fragments display when the first time the top level tabs are traversed. But the "sub"fragments do not display upon a 2nd iteration

Here is how the subtabpager adapter is created in one of the fragments which exist at the top level

public final class MainLevelTabFragment extends Fragment {

```
private SubpageTabsPagerAdapter mSubpagePagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mSubpageViewPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = null;
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_main_level, container, false);
        mSubpageViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.subpage_screen_tabs_pager);
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        mSubpagePagerAdapter = new SubpageTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager, getActivity());
        mSubpageViewPager.setAdapter(mSubpagePagerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

The SubpageTabsPagerAdapter code looks like this

```
public class SubpageTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public SubpageTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (null == mCursor)
            return null;

        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        Fragment fragment = new SubtabFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (null != mCursor) ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (null == mCursor)
            return null;

        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        return "title";
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        if (mCursor == c)
            return;

        mCursor = c;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your `SubpageTabsPagerAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Yep that's it. getChildFragmentManager() solves the inconsistent behavior. Thank you stkent!

Comment: Glad to help.  Please return the favor by marking my answer as correct.  Thx